# Change the order of magnitude on the y axis Ticks with ListPlot

Tags: plotting

I have some data plotted with ListPlot. 
The values on the y axis range from -411230.40068*10^9 to -411230.20005*10^9.

Mathematica, when plotting the data, shows me on the y axis only the value -4.1123*10^14 for every tick. Is there any way to make him show the numbers in powers of 10^9, and with 10 digits of precision? I tried with `Ticks` but didn't get so far.

Thank you

EDITED:

A sample on request :)

`data2={{1, {-5.54852437936809996398746480994*10^15, \
-1.58405160806420515488174765341*10^15, \
-1.54904996250380274306639604529*10^15, \
-7.24548530142209283870114553464*10^14, \
-7.18837770040996237092450275609*10^14, \
-7.15800320331340464813219293321*10^14, \
-4.11230259670690940795492506374*10^14, \
-4.11230258208178097437386932781*10^14, \
-4.11230256745665254647574651356*10^14, \
-4.11230253333135289454398509564*10^14}},{201, {-5.54852437888387950167782712058*10^15, \
-1.58405160700141010456248575686*10^15, \
-1.54904996124562038459636927190*10^15, \
-7.24548527010296055168304870775*10^14, \
-7.18837765300540306484560667009*10^14, \
-7.15800315786888059026593182124*10^14, \
-4.11230245162563527615111099610*10^14, \
-4.11230245150863424853646162039*10^14, \
-4.11230245139163322092217595244*10^14, \
-4.11230245111863082315635188077*10^14}}}`

This is what I use to plot them:

`ListPlot[Transpose[Thread[#] & /@ data2], 
 PlotRange -> {-4.112303*10^14, -4.112302*10^14}, Joined -> True, 
 Mesh -> All, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.002]]`

Comment: "some data" - I can't seem to find it anywhere in your post...

Comment: Can you show us what you tried with `Ticks`?